# how to change the image folder name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project there is an option to add image for country which is stored in 'storage\app\public\countries' path. Now in the same form i have an option to add the name of the country,so what i needed is in the image url - '/countries_nameoftheCountry/image'. I wanted to rename the /countries folder to '/countries_nameoftheCountry' to achieve the above url In this way there will be multiple folders with different country name and inside it i will store the image of particular country respectively.

Please suggest if there is better way of doing this, Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO, your folder should be the [iso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) of the country ex: Afghanistan -> AFG. But this approach you will have a lot of folders, My other suggestion is country name is the image name + extension (better seo).